# JSON can't access data returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following code,

```
var json = [
    {
        "name": "Fashion Forward",
        "good": {
            "doors" : {
                "name1" : "ff_good_doors_1.jpg",
                "name2" : "ff_good_doors_2.jpg",
                "name3" : "ff_good_doors_3.jpg"
            }
        },
        "better": {

        },
        "best": {

        }

    }
]
```

I would expect to be able get data out by doing something like,

`json.name` which I would expect to contain "Fashion Forward" - however I get `undefined` return, but if I `console.log(json)` I can see that it is an object.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `json.name` is undefined. `json[0]` isn't though.

Comment: The square brackets [] create an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`json` is the name of the array, you can use like this **`json[0].name;`**

Answer (score 1):

Why you use `Array` ? if you want to access members like what you already said :

> I would expect to be able get data out by doing something like,
>
> **`json.name`** which I would expect to contain "Fashion Forward" - however
>   I get undefined return, but if I `console.log(json)` I can see that it
>   is an `object`.
>
> Where am I going wrong?

use this code and remove array:

```
var json =    {
   "name": "Fashion Forward",
   "good": {
       "doors" : {
           "name1" : "ff_good_doors_1.jpg",
           "name2" : "ff_good_doors_2.jpg",
           "name3" : "ff_good_doors_3.jpg"
       }
   },
   "better": {},
   "best": {}
}
```

Now you may use `json.name`

Comment: yeah this is a better choice. :-) @Udders

Answer (score 0):

As it looks from your code, **json** is an array of single item. Try this

```
json[0].name
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

the **json variable is an array**. to get the first object you need to select it like this `json[0]` and then you can access the the name property like this

`var name = json[0].name;`